# How to make api calls in batches of 100 calls per second per request in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am developing an sms sending php system the server can only handle 100 calls per request. How can I make 100 API calls per second per request when I'm sending large data of messages of about 5000+,

here is my PHP code

```
$phones = $_POST['recipient_phones']; //get phone numbers from textarea
$phones = chop($phones,","); //remove last comma
$phones = multiexplode(array(","," ","\r\n",".","|",":"),$phones);//reformat and convert to array
$sender = $_POST['sender_id']; //Get Sender ID input field
$message = $_POST['message']; //Get Message input field
$link_id = $rand_link_id;
$correlator = $randCorrelator;
$endpoint = 'https://exampleurl.com';

foreach($phones as $phone){

$data = array("link_id" => "$link_id", "sender" => "$sender","phone" => "$phone", "message" => "$message","endpoint" => "$endpoint","correlator" => "$correlator");

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://bulk.example.com/api/v1/send-sms');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json','Accept: application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$token,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$smsResults = curl_exec($ch);
sleep(3);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Use Guzzle and send async requests

Comment: How can I perform this?

Comment: You could always just `array_chunk` the bulk into 100-batches to be looped, then note the `microtime` at the start of a 100-batch, and `usleep` for the remainder of each second when each 100-batch is done.

Comment: Thank you I will try it out